# Light: reflection and transmission

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

When white light hits a thin "transparent material", is there a general relationship between the spectra of the reflected and transmitted components?

For example, do red filters (that make things look red when viewed through them) also look red when light is shined upon them? Or is this not necessarily true?

Answer (score 1):

"White" light is a bit ambiguous. Let's just call it a mixed spectrum of wavelengths in the visible spectrum for now.
Now, for a given material, assuming it is semitransparent, there is a spectrally varying reflection coefficient.  The light that isn't reflected has the complement to that curve (highly reflected light means very little is not reflected, etc.). Then apply the spectral absorptance curve to see what light makes it to the second surface.  Once again, apply the spectral reflectance curve, essentially repeating the spectral loss curve of the first surface.

So, in the case of zero absorptance, the reflectance curve and the transmittance curves will be "opposite" to each other.  I'm leaving out the possible [etalon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabry%E2%80%93P%C3%A9rot_interferometer) behavior due to the internally reflected light going back to the first surface, partially reflecting/transmitting there, and so on for innumerable round-trip reflections.

Comment: Thanks.. but I guess absorption is the free variable ? In my perception, red and green filters, that make things viewed through them red and green, also look red and green themselves (based on the light they reflect) - or don't they ?